# Looking for a linux command - concatenate two files - sort by last name and delete duplicates - store in new file

Tags: linux, bash, sorting, command-line, uniq

I'm trying to concatenate two files, sort them by last name, delete duplicates and store them in a new file.

File's: "firstName lastName"

FileA + FileB --> FileC

I tried it with the sort command:

sort -uk2 fileA fileB > fileC

The problem is that this command deletes names with the same last name but diffrent first name.

"Hans Smith" + "Hans Smith" --> only one "Hans Smith" should remain.
"Friedrich Bauer" + "Colin Bauer" --> should both be kept.

Any ideas?

Comment: Try `man uniq`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First sort the whole lines and remove duplicates then sort by the second field:

```
sort -u fileA fileB | sort -k2 > fileC
```

Comment: To my surprise, this is ~3 times faster than any of my two suggestions. I really don't understand how that can be. The one I expected to be fastest, `sort -u -k2 -k1` is the slowest :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can split up sorting and removing duplicates in two operations. First sort on `-k2`, then use `uniq` to remove duplicates.

```bash
sort -k2 fileA fileB | uniq > fileC
```

Or, `sort` on the first name too:

```bash
sort -u -k2 -k1 fileA fileB > fileC
```